# Finding the fixed point through which Family of straight line passes through

Tags: geometry

My book states the following:

> If a straight line is such that the algebraic sum of the
> perpendiculars drawn from any number of fixed point is $0$, then the
> straight line always passes through a fixed point.

What does it mean?

**Edit1:**

[image]

**Edit2:**
In the Material provided by @MattSamuel, how does the **method (i)** work? It states the following:

> ***Method (i)***
>
> Let the family of straight lines be of the form ax + by + c = 0 where
> a, b, c are variable parameters satisfying the condition al + bm + cn
> = 0, where l , m , n are given and n ≠ 0. Rewriting the condition as  , and comparing with the given family of straight lines, we find that
> each member of it passes through the fixed point

Comment: Beats me. ${} {} {} {} $

Comment: Beats me too. This is exactly what my book states. Is it correct or not?

Comment: What a confusing textbook!

Comment: It looks like we're missing some surrounding details. What is the subject? What space are these lines in? What is a fixed point?

Comment: I found this related material. http://www.quantumstudy.com/mathematics/straight-line-8a/

Comment: If one choose a coordinate so that the "line" is the $x$-axis, then the signed perpendicular of any point to that line is the $y$-coordinate of that point.
If the signed perpendicular of a bunch of points sum to $0$, the $y$-coordinate of the centroid of those points sum to $0$. This means the centroid lies on the $x$-axis. The condition is a strange way to say when the sum of signed perpendicular is $0$, then the line passes through the centroid.

Comment: Please check Edit2.